NPM module import
I downloaded library jQuery using npm i jquery:

Then tried to use it in my .js file.
I used import $ from 'jquery':

It doesn't work
I expected my .c object to disappear:

but it didn't:

However, when I use cdn to connect jQuery, it works. But I don't want to use a cdn.

Don't post screenshots of code. Paste the text.

it seemed that you are importing jQuery in your js.js file and then you are using that js.js file in index.html.Right?

Yes, you are right

Did you check by inspecting that your .js file is properly loaded?I am asking cz in my system its working file.

Also remove :void from (funtion() :void {.. in your js.js file ,bacause it is a type- annotations used in .ts file. And then check again

It cant be removed

Alse js.js is loaded properly. If i use like this:




Title

<style>
    .c
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>







And my js look like this
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".c").fadeOut();
})
iI works good.  There is problem with import
you have
<script src="index.js">

but that file does not exist suggesting this is been compiled by something like webpack, or Vite and if not you might want to look at using something like that as its easier.
Also, is the path "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" valid and do you get any console errors? try to provide a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
